# How to protect FCM service with permission or something

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I developed an android app with fcm implementation. After completion I done the app vulnerability testing and got the below result.

> (com.app.MyFirebaseMessagingService) is not Protected. An
>   intent-filter exists.
>
> high
>
> A Service is found to be shared with other apps on the device
>   therefore leaving it accessible to any other application on the
>   device. The presence of intent-filter indicates that the Service is
>   explicitly exported.

Same result I got for the service MyFirebaseInstanceIDService. Below is my Manifest file code.

```
        <service android:name="com.app.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.app.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Usually we will add a custom permission to protect a service from get accessed by other application. But how to do that for FCM service? or any other solution for this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to worry about firebase take care of the security side [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService)

> FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
>         no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"